# First time rigging. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: rigging

I'm new to Blender. I managed to create a pretty good 3D version of a mascot. I want to rig the mascot but it's a weird shape and I'm not sure how to get this to work. I've used symmetrize and IK Constraints. When I parent with automatic weights, I have to correct a lot of it with weight painting as it's deforming the shape of the character too much but that gets too messy to sort out. Any tips would be appreciated.[image]
[image]

Comment: I would start making the "shoulder" bones child of the head bone, and top arm bones child of the torso bone, so that 2/3 of the big sphere moves as one piece. Then with such a particular shape some manual weight paint is needed indeed.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this

Comment: Well The sphere seems better but the legs are contorted and I can't undo it with weight painting. Starting to think I need to put my character in a more traditional t-pose in order to get the rig to work.

Comment: If you need some more help, please provide the file, or some pictures of the problems and the wireframe of the character.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VGCFG9Zo5Kz0u0yAaDfipl8aCDy22D-p/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Basically once I parent with automatic weights, the arms, legs and butt/hip region are warped and when I try correcting it with weight painting it gets messy. The file I provided above is not yet parented.

Comment: 340 Mb is too much. I think you need a retopology before attempting at rigging.

Comment: Ok thanks I will give that a try. I really appreciate the advice.

Comment: Is it possible to use decimate, boolean and/or remesh modiefiers to make it more simple rather than manual retopology?

Comment: Update- I got the file size down to about 10,000 kb by simplifying the mesh and reducing the number of faces and vertices. How I did that was by changing the subdivisions I added to smooth the surfaces to the lowest number possible, I also used decimate with Collapse mode to lower the Ratio number as far as I could. I also went in and deleted some extra vertices that were hidden inside the character's body. After getting everything as low-poly as possible without ruining its curvature, I then reconstructed the rig from scratch and Parented the rig to the character with automatic weights.